# Use proxy sentences from cleaned data

Tags: python, nlp, gensim, word2vec, word-embedding

Gensim's `Word2Vec` model takes as an  input a list of lists with the inner list containing individual tokens/words of a sentence. As I understand `Word2Vec` is used to "quantify" the context of words within a text using vectors. 
I am currently dealing with a corpus of text that has already been split into individual tokens and no longer contains an obvious sentence format (punctuation has been removed). I was wondering how should I input this into the `Word2Vec` model?

Say if I simply split the corpus into "sentences" of uniform length (10 tokens per sentence for example), would this be a good way of inputting the data into the model?

Essentially, **I am wondering how the format of the input sentences (list of lists) affects the output of Word2Vec?**

Answer (score 1):

That sounds like a reasonable solution. If you have access to data that is similar to your cleaned data you could get average sentence length from that data set. Otherwise, you could find other data in the language you are working with (from wikipedia or another source) and get average sentence length from there.

Of course your output vectors will not be as reliable as if you had the correct sentence boundaries, but it sounds like word order was preserved so there shouldn't be too much noise from incorrect sentence boundaries.

Answer (score 1):

Most typically, text is passed to `Word2Vec` in logical units (like sentences or paragraphs). Also, the published papers and early demo code tended to convert punctuation into tokens, as well.

But text without punctuation, and arbitrary breaks between texts, are a reasonable workaround and still give pretty good results.

For example, the `text8`/`text9` corpuses often used in demos (including the [word2vec intro Jupyter notebook bundled in gensim](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/develop/docs/notebooks/word2vec.ipynb)) are just giant runs-of-words, lacking punctuation and line-breaks. So, the utility `LineSentence` class used in gensim will break them into individual 10,000-token texts.

It's probably better to go *larger* in your arbitrary breaks (eg 10,000), rather than smaller (eg 10), for a couple reasons:

- source texts are usually longer than 10 words
- often the source material that was run-together was still semantically-related across its original boundaries
- the optimized algorithms work better on larger chunks of data
- the harm of "false context windows" (created by the concatenation) is probably just noise with no net biasing effect, while more "true windows" (by creating as few false splits as possible) likely retains more of the original corpus' learnable word-to-word relationships signal
- you can always simulate more-conservative contexts with a smaller `window` parameter (if the original source really did have tiny sentences that weren't sequentially-related)

But, gensim's cython-optimized training path has an implementation limit of 10,000 tokens per text – with any more being silently ignored – so you wouldn't intentionally want to supply longer texts for any reason.